# Output receiving GND by activating the transistor

Tags: transistors

The base of my transistor is activated with a positive signal 5v. I need that when this happens my output OUT receives GND, but I do not know if I should connect OUT on the collector and GND on the emitter or the opposite GND on the collector and OUT on the emitter. Usually my output is connected to a pull-up resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo0kvo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. A standard NPN switch.*

Feeding a current into the base of the transistor turns it on and current can flow from the collector to the emitter.

The emitter is connected to GND and the load - or in your case the pullup - is connected to the collector.

Be aware that the signal gets inverted. When OUTPUT switches high the collector is pulled low.

Comment: I did not understand where my "IN" is connected in your circuit.

Comment: The micro-controller output is connected to the IN of your circuit. My R1 is the same as yours. Your R2 is optional and generally not required for a digital 'on-off' signal. See http://lednique.com/driving-leds-on-higher-voltage/.